# How do I install mp3pro support?

Tags: rhythmbox, codecs

I've been listening to some of my older music today and I've just come across an album that I ripped back in my 'mp3pro days'... Needless to say it doesn't sound very good, which I'm guessing is because Rhythmbox falling back to normal mp3 (at only 96kbps) instead of playing the mp3pro 'extras' so it sounds tolerable :)

Are there codecs that I can use to get mp3pro sounding less horrible or an alternative music player that supports the format? Alternatively, does Rhythmbox already support the format and I'd just not realised how bad it sounds before?

Obviously I'll re-rip it if it comes to that, but it's a hassle I'd rather avoid. (especially since I have quite a few of them)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several (possible) solutions for your problem [documented here](http://users.softlab.ntua.gr/~ttsiod/mp3pro.html).

It boils down to using Windows software (possibly under Wine) or using the closed source plugin for XMMS.  XMMS 1.x itself isn't part of Ubuntu anymore, but maybe you can use it via MPlayer.

You can then convert the music to another format using one of those tools.

Comment: The linked article is fantastic, thanks! It looks like the easiest way for me will be to re-rip them (I don't like the idea of transcoding from a relatively low bitrate and I'd rather use Rhythmbox than MPlayer) but this will be a great help for people who don't have that option!

Comment: If you have the original media and enough free time, re-ripping is the best solution of course!