# How to install and run xmms

Tags: installation, gui, xmms

I [hear](https://askubuntu.com/a/8531/47206) that XMMS1 is not available in Ubuntu anymore (what does that mean exactly?), but in Synaptic I see a lot of stuff related to XMMS2 (By the way, what's the difference?). I have installed these but now cannot seem able to start it.
How to use XMMS? Is there a GUI form of it, like it appears [here](http://www.xmms.org/) and [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2036856)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [XMMS](http://www.xmms.org/)

This cross-platform Unix player was not further developed to meet requirements of newer version of Ubuntu and was thus removed from the repositories.

---

### [XMMS2](http://xmms2.org/wiki/Main_Page)

The presently available version of a similar music player.

[image: Install via the software center]

---

### [Gxmms2](http://wejp.k.vu/projects/xmms2/gxmms2)

This is a Gtk2 graphical frontend for XMMS2.

[image: Install via the software center]

---

### [Audacious](http://audacious-media-player.org/)

An alternative lightweight and skinnable musice player initially forked from XMMS.

[image: Install via the software center]

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://xmms2.org/wiki/Using_the_application) are the official instructions on the XMMS2 wiki.

Take a look at the list of clients [here](http://xmms2.org/wiki/XMMS2_Clients#gxmms2_.28GTK.29) on the same wiki. Abraca, for example, can be installed via `sudo apt-get install abraca` and will load other dependencies, including xmms2 itself. Nice and easy.

Answer (score 0):

As I have found [here](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/xmms), 
"one of its main developers rewrote the player, as the XMMS2, which is actively developed and present in official packages".

There is an XMMS2 GUI called `promoe`

(apt links to xmms2 and promoe at the above address)

To install skins (see [here](http://xmms2.org/wiki/Client%3aPromoe)):

"Promoe can be configured to use Winamp Classic skins. Skins are toggled within the 'Theme settings' menu feature.
To install new skins:
    Go to the directory /home/**user**/.config/xmms2/clients/
        (If using a file browser, you may need to adjust the settings so that hidden files are shown. 
    Create a new folder called 'promoe' and an additional folder within ../promoe/ called 'skins'.
        Any new skins can now be extracted into their own respective folders within /home/**user**/.config/xmms2/clients/promoe/skins/ "